# Insertar varios datos en MySQL con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

Estoy intentando guardar los datos de un archivo `CSV` que estoy descargando de la Web y estos mismos los quiero insertar a la **bd**, pero no me permite hacerlo, sé que debo agregarle un ciclo para que me vaya iterando los datos, pero no sé cómo colocarlo, agradecería mucho su ayuda.
Tengo 2 condiciones, una para la inserción inicial y otro para la actualización en caso de que ya tenga datos.

Según mi idea era colocar un ciclo `for`, pero como les digo, no se como armarlo. No sé, estaría genial que me puedan apoyar con un ejemplo para darme una idea.

```
    <?php
/* El siguiente código se encarga de realizar la descarga del archivo de descripcion
* de los contribuyentes con algún tipo de adeudo ante el SAT, a través de la libreria
* CURL de php.
*/

header('Content-type: application/json');

/* Hace el llamado a la conexion a la BD */
require "../../APIs/conexion.php";

/* URL desde dónde se hará la descarga del archivo en formato excel .csv */
$url =  "http://omawww.sat.gob.mx/cifras_sat/Documents/Listado_Completo_69-B.csv";

/* Inicializa la función para obtener el archivo de la URL */
$ch = curl_init($url);

/* Devuelve el resultado de la transferencia como string */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

/* Ejecuta la descarga del archivo desde la URL */
$output = curl_exec($ch);

/* Realiza el guardado del archivo con el nombre listasNegras.csv y se le da la propiedad de solo lectura con 'w' */
$fh = fopen('listasNegras.csv', 'w');

/* Verifica que el archivo se haya guardado correctamente en el mismo directorio donde se encuentra guardado descargaIncumplidos.php */
if(fwrite($fh, $output))
{
    echo "Guardado con exito!"; //Si fue guardado correctamente, manda un mensaje en pantalla
}
else
{
    echo "No guardado"; //De lo contrario, también manda un mensaje en pantalla
}


/* Cierra el archivo creado listasNegras.csv */
fclose($fh);


/* Comprueba la existencia del archivo descargado */
if(file_exists('listasNegras.csv'))
{
    /* Mensaje en pantalla que indica que el archivo existe */
    echo "\n Existe\n";

    /* Bandera que demarca las filas del archivo */
    $j = 0;

    /* Abre el archivo con privilegios de lectura y escritura */
    if(($fh = fopen('listasNegras.csv', 'r')) !== false)
    {
        /* Comprueba que la tabla no tenga nigun */
        if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM catContribuyentes")) < 1)
        {
            /* Mensaje de salida que indica el resultado de la comparacion anterior */
            echo "NO hay!\n";

            /* Mientras el archivo contenga datos, se mostrarán en pantalla los datos del archivo */
            while(($file = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ',')) !== false)
            {
                /* Se mostrarán todas las filas excepto las primeras 3, las cuales de acuerdo al documento, no necesitamos guardar en la base */
                if($j > 2)
                {
                    /* Imprime en pantalla los datos del archivo .CSV */
                    echo utf8_encode($file[0]."\t".$file[2]."\t".$file[17]."\n");

                    $num = count($file);


                    /* Sentencia que inserta los datos en la tabla de la base */
                    if(mysqli_query($conectar, "INSERT INTO catContribuyentes (noContri, rfcContri, nombreContri, situacionContri, numFecContri, publicacionContri, numFecContriP, pubDOFContri, pubDesvContri, numFecDesvContri, publicacionDOFDes, numFecDefi, punlicacionDefi, publicacionDOFDef, numFecSentFav, pubSentSATFav, numFecSentFavD, pubDOFSentFav) VALUES ('$file[0]', '$file[1]', '$file[2]', '$file[3]', '$file[4]', '$file[5]', '$file[6]', '$file[7]', '$file[8]', '$file[9]', '$file[10]', '$file[11]', '$file[12]', '$file[13]', '$file[14]', '$file[15]', '$file[16]', '$file[17]')"))
                    {
                        echo "Guardado\n"; //Mensaje en pantalla

                        echo $num;

                        /* Cierra el archivo creado listasNegras.csv */
                        fclose($fh);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "No se guardo\n"; //Mensaje en pantalla
                    }
                }
                $j++; //Se incrementa la variable en uno
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "\n Ya hay registros\n";
            /* Mientras el archivo contenga datos, se mostrarán en pantalla los datos del archivo */
            while(($file = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ',')) !== false)
            {
                /* Se mostrarán todas las filas excepto las primeras 3, las cuales de acuerdo al documento, no necesitamos guardar en la base */
                if($j > 2)
                {
                    /* Imprime en pantalla los datos del archivo .CSV */
                    //echo utf8_encode($file[0]."\t".$file[2]."\t".$file[17]."\n");
                    $num = count($file);                    

                    /* Sentencia que inserta los datos en la tabla de la base */
                    if(mysqli_query($conectar, "UPDATE catContribuyentes SET noContri = '$file[0]', rfcContri = '$file[1]', nombreContri = '$file[2]', situacionContri = '$file[3]', numFecContri = '$file[4]', publicacionContri = '$file[5]', numFecContriP = '$file[6]', pubDOFContri = '$file[7]', pubDesvContri = '$file[8]', numFecDesvContri = '$file[9]', publicacionDOFDes = '$file[10]', numFecDefi = '$file[11]', punlicacionDefi = '$file[12]', publicacionDOFDef = '$file[13]', numFecSentFav = '$file[14]', pubSentSATFav = '$file[15]', numFecSentFavD = '$file[16]', pubDOFSentFav = '$file[17]'"))
                    {
                        echo "Actualizado\n"; //Mensaje en pantalla

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "No se actualizo\n"; //Mensaje en pantalla
                    }
                }
                $j++; //Se incrementa la variable en uno
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No se abrió";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "\n no Existe";
}
?>
```

Comment: En realidad, ya estás iterando por todas las filas del csv con while(($file = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ',')) !== false). ¿Qué error sale o qué pasa cuando tratas de insertar los datos?

Comment: Creo que la pregunta está mal formulada. Sería algo como ... obtener los datos de un csv y hacer uso de los datos. Mira de reformular la pregunta.

Comment: Es correcto, cuando muestro en pantalla los datos me los muestra todos, pero cuando meto la sentencia SQL solo me inserta una fila al azar de todas las que obtiene. Por eso pensaba que me hacía falta un ciclo o algo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un ejemplo sencillo de cómo hacer esto.

- Obtienes el string del csv.
- En el primer `foreach` obtienes las líneas.
- Anidas un segundo `foreach` para obtener los campos.

Con `explode` conviertes los strings en arrays, para poderlos itinerar con `foreach`.

Te dejo un ejemplo.
*Adaptalo a tu código.*

EL ejemplo se supone que cada línea está dividida por un salto de linea `\n` y cada campo dividido entre `;`

```php
   // En este caso lo obtenemos directamente. Para simplificar el ejemplo.
    $url =  "http://localhost/path/a/tu/archivo.csv";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // $output es el contenido del csv en un string
    var_dump($output);

    // Dividir el string en arrays con cada línea.
    $lineas = explode('\n', $output);

    // Ahora $lineas es un array con todas las lineas del csv
    var_dump($lineas);


    // Itineramos las lineas.
    foreach ($lineas as $nombre=>$linea) {

      // Dividimos cada linea en array.
      $campos =explode(';',$linea);

      // $campos es un array con los campos de cada linea.
      var_dump($campos);

      // Itineramos cada campo de cada línea
      foreach($campos as $nombre_campo=>$valor_campo) {

        echo "<br/> $nombre_campo => $valor_campo";
      }

    }
```

Info sobre `explode`: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

---

**Usando str_getcsv()**

Puedes utilizar una función de PHP que tambień te puede facilitar la cosa.

Ejemplo sencillo de uso:

```php
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($url));

var_dump($csv);
```

En este caso de nuevo es posible que tengas  que utilizar explode sino te dejo al final una librería que es más cómoda de usar...

Info sobre str-getcsv : https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-getcsv.php

---

**Librería para convertir CSV en objetos php: *php-csv-parser***

Tienes una pequeña libreira que puede facilitarte la faena: https://github.com/jamesgordo/php-csv-parser

Ejemplo de uso de la librería...

```php
<?php
// load vendor autoload
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use JamesGordo\CSV\Parser;

// Initalize the Parser
$users = new Parser('/path/to/users.csv');

// loop through each user and echo the details
foreach($users->all() as $user) {
    echo "User Details: {$user->id} | {$user->first_name} {$user->last_name}";
}

echo "Total Parsed: " . $users->count() . " Users";
```

Comment: Y para transferir ciertos elementos del array que obtengo del CSV, ¿hay algún tipo de función? ¿O de que manera podría yo hacerlo?

Comment: Puedes usar la función  `var_dump($tus_datos)`, para saber que tipo de datos estas obteniendo, de esa forma sabrás como tratarlos. Ya que te indicará si es un array, objeto, string, etc... El `var_dump()` lo puedes usar siempre que tengas dudas de como tratar los datos obtenidos.  (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias, es que de hecho recibo puros strings, pero quiero que ciertos elementos de ese [tag:CSV], los guarde en otra matriz o array, para posteriormente darles otro tratamiento más tarde. Sólo tengo la duda de como se como declarar la matriz y como se guardan.

Comment: Si te fijas en el primer ejemplo de esta respuesta. Hemos "partido" el string en lineas y ahora tenemos la variable  `$lineas` convertido en un array de `strings`.  En el foreach itineramos el array para sacar cada linea, entonces cojemos cada linea (que es un String) y lo convertimos en array `$campos` ahora `$campos` contiene un array con los campos. Hacemos otro foreach para ir imprimiendo cada campo.  Edito el primer ejemplo con unos `var_dump()` para que puedas ver el proceso por pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

He intentado hacerlo con el ciclo for, me da los resultados, pero no me permite insertarlos a la base de datos. Lo he intentado de mil formas, pero no me deja. Éste es el código:

```
<?php
/* El siguiente código se encarga de realizar la descarga del archivo de descripcion
* de los contribuyentes con algún tipo de adeudo ante el SAT, a través de la libreria
* CURL de php.
* Ejemplo de código basado en http://soyprogramador.liz.mx/bajar-archivos-con-curl/
* Puedes consultar la manipulación de archivos en http://soyprogramador.liz.mx/manipulacion-de-archivos-php/
* En este enlace hay informacuón sobre como manejar los archivos .CSV https://csv.thephpleague.com/
*/

header('Content-type: application/json');

/* Hace el llamado a la conexion a la BD */
require "../../APIs/conexion.php";

/* URL desde dónde se hará la descarga del archivo en formato excel .csv */
$url =  "http://omawww.sat.gob.mx/cifras_sat/Documents/Listado_Completo_69-B.csv";

/* Inicializa la función para obtener el archivo de la URL */
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

/* Devuelve el resultado de la transferencia como string */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

/* Ejecuta la descarga del archivo desde la URL */
$output = curl_exec($ch);

$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($url));

//var_dump($csv);

$insertados = 0;
$actualizados = 0;
$errores = 0;


$nRegistros = count($csv);
echo $nRegistros."\n";
//var_dump($csv);
if(file_exists('listasNegras.csv'))
{
    /* Mensaje en pantalla que indica que el archivo existe */
    echo "\n Existe\n";

    if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM catContribuyentes")) == 0)
    {
        /* Mensaje en pantalla que indica que el archivo existe */
        echo "\n No hay registros, se puede insertar\n";

        for ($i = 3; $i < $nRegistros; $i++)
        {
            for ($j=0; $j < count($csv[$i]); $j++)
            {
                echo utf8_encode($csv[$i][$j])."\n";
            }
        }
    }
}


echo "Registros Insertados: ".$insertados."\n";
echo "Errores durante la inserción: ".$errores."\n";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo he logrado hacer, dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve

```
    <?php
/* El siguiente código se encarga de realizar la descarga del archivo de descripción
* de los contribuyentes con algún tipo de adeudo ante el SAT, a través de la libreria
* CURL de php.
* Ejemplo de código basado en http://soyprogramador.liz.mx/bajar-archivos-con-curl/
* Aunque en la versión final del archivo ya no se usó,
* puedes consultar la manipulación de archivos en http://soyprogramador.liz.mx/manipulacion-de-archivos-php/
* En este enlace hay información sobre como manejar los archivos .CSV https://csv.thephpleague.com/
*/

header('Content-type: application/json');

/* Hace el llamado a la conexion a la BD */
require "../../APIs/conexion.php";

/* URL desde dónde se hará la descarga del archivo en formato excel .csv */
$url =  "http://omawww.sat.gob.mx/cifras_sat/Documents/Listado_Completo_69-B.csv";

/* Inicializa la función para obtener el archivo de la URL */
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

/* Devuelve el resultado de la transferencia como string */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

/* Ejecuta la descarga del archivo desde la URL */
$output = curl_exec($ch);

/* Convierte los datos del archivo en un array */
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($url));

//var_dump($csv);

/* Variables que serviran como contadores para saber cuantos registros se actualizaron, insertaron o si hubo errores */
$insertados = 0;
$actualizados = 0;
$errores = 0;

/* Cuenta cuantos registros tiene el archivo descargado */
$nRegistros = count($csv);

/* Muestra en pantalla la cantidad de registros del archivo */
echo $nRegistros."\n";

/* Muestra en pantalla el arreglo convertido */
//var_dump($csv);

/* Comprueba la existencia del archivo descargado */
if(file_exists('listasNegras.csv'))
{
    /* Mensaje en pantalla que indica que el archivo existe */
    echo "\n Existe\n";

    /* Evalua si la tabla tiene registros insertados */
    if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM catContribuyentes")) == 0)
    {
        /* Mensaje en pantalla que la condi */
        echo "\n No hay registros, se puede insertar\n";

        /* Este ciclo se encarga de recorrer las posiciones del arreglo */
        for ($i = 3; $i <= $nRegistros-1; $i++)
        {
            /* Muestra en pantalla algunos de los datos del archivo */
            echo utf8_encode($csv[$i][0]."\t".$csv[$i][1]."\t".$csv[$i][2]."\t".$csv[$i][3]."\n");

            /* Hace la asignacion de los datos del array a las variables, además de hacer la conversión a UTF8 para poder hacer la visualización de los acentos */
            $noContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][0]);
            $rfcContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][1]);
            $nombreContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][2]);
            $situacionContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][3]);
            $numFecContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][4]);
            $publicacionContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][5]);
            $numFecContriP = utf8_encode($csv[$i][6]);
            $pubDOFContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][7]);
            $pubDesvContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][8]);
            $numFecDesvContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][9]);
            $publicacionDOFDes = utf8_encode($csv[$i][10]);
            $numFecDefi = utf8_encode($csv[$i][11]);
            $punlicacionDefi = utf8_encode($csv[$i][12]);
            $publicacionDOFDef = utf8_encode($csv[$i][13]);
            $numFecSentFav = utf8_encode($csv[$i][14]);
            $pubSentSATFav = utf8_encode($csv[$i][15]);
            $numFecSentFavD = utf8_encode($csv[$i][16]);
            $pubDOFSentFav = utf8_encode($csv[$i][17]);

            /* Sentencia SQL para hacer la insercion en la tabla */
            $sql = "INSERT INTO catContribuyentes (noContri, rfcContri, nombreContri, situacionContri, numFecContri, publicacionContri, numFecContriP, pubDOFContri, pubDesvContri, numFecDesvContri, publicacionDOFDes, numFecDefi, punlicacionDefi, publicacionDOFDef, numFecSentFav, pubSentSATFav, numFecSentFavD, pubDOFSentFav) VALUES ('$noContri', '$rfcContri', '$nombreContri', '$situacionContri', '$numFecContri', '$publicacionContri', '$numFecContriP', '$pubDOFContri', '$pubDesvContri', '$numFecDesvContri', '$publicacionDOFDes', '$numFecDefi', '$punlicacionDefi', '$publicacionDOFDef', '$numFecSentFav', '$pubSentSATFav', '$numFecSentFavD', '$pubDOFSentFav')";

            /* Evaluación y ejecución de la sentencia SQL */
            if(mysqli_query($conectar, $sql))
            {
                $insertados++; //Cuenta registros insertados
            }
            else
            {
                /* Muestra en pantalla el error que se pudo generar mediante la inserción */
                echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".mysqli_error($conectar)."\n";
                $errores++; //Cueenta la cantidad de erroes generados
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        /* Mensaje en pantalla que indica la condición de la tabla */
        echo "\n Ya hay registros, se procedera a actualizar\n";

        for ($i = 3; $i <= $nRegistros-1; $i++)
        {
            /* Muestra en pantalla algunos de los datos del archivo */
            echo utf8_encode($csv[$i][0]."\t".$csv[$i][1]."\t".$csv[$i][2]."\t".$csv[$i][3]."\n");

            /* Hace la asignacion de los datos del array a las variables, además de hacer la conversión a UTF8 para poder hacer la visualización de los acentos */
            $noContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][0]);
            $rfcContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][1]);
            $nombreContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][2]);
            $situacionContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][3]);
            $numFecContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][4]);
            $publicacionContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][5]);
            $numFecContriP = utf8_encode($csv[$i][6]);
            $pubDOFContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][7]);
            $pubDesvContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][8]);
            $numFecDesvContri = utf8_encode($csv[$i][9]);
            $publicacionDOFDes = utf8_encode($csv[$i][10]);
            $numFecDefi = utf8_encode($csv[$i][11]);
            $punlicacionDefi = utf8_encode($csv[$i][12]);
            $publicacionDOFDef = utf8_encode($csv[$i][13]);
            $numFecSentFav = utf8_encode($csv[$i][14]);
            $pubSentSATFav = utf8_encode($csv[$i][15]);
            $numFecSentFavD = utf8_encode($csv[$i][16]);
            $pubDOFSentFav = utf8_encode($csv[$i][17]);

            /* Sentencia SQL para hacer la insercion en la tabla */
            $sql = "UPDATE catContribuyentes SET noContri = '$noContri', rfcContri = '$rfcContri', nombreContri = '$nombreContri', situacionContri = '$situacionContri', numFecContri = '$numFecContri', publicacionContri = '$publicacionContri', numFecContriP = '$numFecContriP', pubDOFContri = '$pubDOFContri', pubDesvContri = '$pubDesvContri', numFecDesvContri = '$numFecDesvContri', publicacionDOFDes = '$publicacionDOFDes', numFecDefi = '$numFecDefi', punlicacionDefi = '$punlicacionDefi', publicacionDOFDef = '$publicacionDOFDef', numFecSentFav = '$numFecSentFav', pubSentSATFav = '$pubSentSATFav', numFecSentFavD = '$numFecSentFavD', pubDOFSentFav = '$pubDOFSentFav'";

            /* Evaluación y ejecución de la sentencia SQL */
            if(mysqli_query($conectar, $sql))
            {
                $actualizados++; //Cuenta registros insertados
            }
            else
            {
                /* Muestra en pantalla el error que se pudo generar mediante la actualización */
                echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".mysqli_error($conectar)."\n";
                $errores++; //Cueenta la cantidad de erroes generados
            }
        }
    }
}

/* Muestra en pantalla la cantidad de registros insertdos y actualizados, así como también la cantidad de errores generados */
echo "Registros Insertados: ".$insertados."\n";
echo "Errores durante la inserción: ".$errores."\n";
echo "Registros actualizados: ".$actualizados."\n";
?>
```